# OSGeo4W command line utilities provoke "Access is Denied" error

Tags: osgeo4w, osgeo, windows-10, command-line

I regularly use OSGeo4W's Advanced Install to update and add packages. I have a Windows 10 Enterprise OS with Administrator rights, and a bunch of OSGeo commandline utilities installed.
I installed osm2pgsql. I exclusively use OSGeo4w Shell to work with all command line utilities (ogrinfo, o-help, etc), all of which now result in an "Access is Denied" error, and do not run.

Windows Command Prompt does not have this issue.
I've reinstalled all command line utilities. I've uninstalled & reinstalled osm2pgsql.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely removed OSGeo installation and reinstalled. It seems to have fixed my issue.